# Can't access redux actions from props when working with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I'm pretty new to react and redux and I have been having a problem accessing my redux actions from the props when used in conjunction with react router. I have tried lots of configurations for formatting but no matter what I try the props only have the react router functions i.e. history, match and location. I am using connected-react-router but it does not seems to be doing anything. I have been able to access the redux actions from my nav menu components so I don't think anything is wrong there.

Here is a sample of the latest configuration I tried:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn }
}

const ConnectedApp = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { signOut, signIn }
)(App);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter basename={baseUrl} history={history}>
            <ConnectedApp />
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
  rootElement);
```

and here is inside App:

```
class App extends Component {
    static displayName = App.name;


  render () {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Route exact path='/' component={(props) =><Home {...props}/>} />
            <Route exact path='/LogInExisting' component={(props) => <LogInExisting {...props} />} />
            <Route exact path='/LogInCreate' component={(props) => <LogInCreate {...props} />} />
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is whats trying to access the signIn action:

```
const LogInExisting = (props) => {
    const history = useHistory();

    const handleSignIn = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        var data = {
            UserName: document.getElementById('login').value,
            Password: document.getElementById('password').value
        }

        var response = await fetch('LogInExistingUser', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });

        var respData = await response.json();
        if (!respData.success) {
            //TODO: Error handling
        } else {
            props.signIn();
            history.push('/')
        }
    }
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious but I really could use some help.

Comment: Am I reading your question correctly, you want to access `this.props.isSignedIn`, `this.props.signOut`, and `this.props.signIn` in `App` component? If so can you update your question to include an example of trying to access/use them and what isn't working?

Comment: That is mostly correct, I am trying to access it in the LogInExisting Component, I updated the question with where I am trying to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) (*`history`, `location`, and `match`*) when using the `Route` component's `component` prop function.

```
<Route
  exact
  path='/LogInExisting'
  component={(props) => <LogInExisting {...props} />}
/>
```

Missing is the passing through of the props that were passed to `App`.

```
<Route
  exact
  path='/LogInExisting'
  component={(routeProps) => <LogInExisting {...routeProps} {...this.props} />}
/>
```

You don't want to use an anonymous function on the `component` prop as this will remount the routed component each time `App` renders. Instead, use the `render` prop function, it's meant for this use case. See [Route render methods](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods) for more in-depth explanation.

```
<Route
  exact
  path='/LogInExisting'
  render={(routeProps) => <LogInExisting {...routeProps} {...this.props} />}
/>
```

This being said though, you are using Redux, which is built using the [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), which solves the issue of "props drilling". You shouldn't be passing your redux state and actions down as props like this. Wrap your routed components in the `connect` HOC locally.

```
<Route exact path='/LogInExisting' component={LogInExisting} />
```

LogInExisting

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { signOut, signIn };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LogInExisting);
```

Since `LogInExisting` is a function component, you can use the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks instead of the `connect` HOC.

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { signIn } from '../path/to/actions';

const LogInExisting = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isSignedIn = useSelector(state => state.auth.isSignedIn);

  const history = useHistory();

  const handleSignIn = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    ...

    if (!respData.success) {
      //TODO: Error handling
    } else {
      dispatch(signIn());
      history.push('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, Thank you! That said I was trying something similar to this previously and I'm not really sure how this is different, the only difference is how my MapStateToProps and connect function looked. That was was working in my nav menu functions, would you happen to know why it wasn't working for the login? It looked like how I had it in the index.

Comment: @TylerFuehrer I don't think I could say without actually seeing *that* specific code to see what it's doing.